# Using sharepoint to develop bespoke solution in sharepoint

Tags: 2013, solution-package

I have a solution which I need to implement in Sharepoint 2013. It is not very complicated project, but it is fairly comprehensive.

It will need to have 10-12 pages site to meet a business need and will be used internal users, no extra-net involved. These pages will interact with SharePoint lists.

I have following options to approach this

1) Create Visual Webparts, and deploy them to Server, then create site pages manually and add those webparts.
2) Develop a sharepoint app
3) Use application pages and do development as if I am developing an Asp.net site.

Is there any other recommended approach to such solutions?

Also, is it recommended to use application pages for site specific solutions?

If I use site pages, is it possible to programmatically create a document library, create site pages and add my web parts on it?

I seem to be a bit lost, could you please share your thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the functionality, but without knowing anything about it I can tell you this:

Application pages will not give you much flexibility in presenting or integrating them in SP, like you say, you develop them like any other ASP.NET page. They generally aren't very friendly to users as they take you out of the site context (unless you limit them to dialog-like functionality).

The webparts (why visual webparts per se ?) do give you the option to integrate them on any page in the site.

The App sits somewhere in between depending on how you will present it, but to my knowledge will require the most SP specific knownledge and may be more effort than what you want to achieve. It's major benefit is that it will also work in an SharePoint Online environment.

Comment: Thanks For reply Cameron. Regarding web parts, do you thing it is better to create user controls and add them to web parts rather than using visual web parts?

Comment: Sorry for the long wait. I'd say seperate user controls are better, yes. It's easier to move them afterwards. It helps you think of a WebPart more as a container (like a page) instead of an actual control. You mix and match user controls in them just as you would on an ASP.NET page.